# Scraping Instagrams Tags Photos with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I'm using selenium with python to scrape tags photos in instagram photos.

I'm using the following python code for [this pic](https://www.instagram.com/p/B-paCUrCP1X/) :

```
def GetInfosPost(self):
    try :
        TagsPhoto=self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name('eg3Fv')
    except :
        TagsPhoto = None

    for TagPhoto in TagsPhoto :
        print (TagPhoto)
```

Expected output is :

- topcorsicaphoto
- corsicaandworld
- visitcorsica etc. (all the tag on the
  pic).

Currently, i have the following output :

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="dbab9a8b6ee85103e421bcf12650ccb8", element="ced09e58-511e-401b-8b9f-968c4f7ac311")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="dbab9a8b6ee85103e421bcf12650ccb8", element="c6efc579-10e3-45d8-b05c-2ea28ebf26d9")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="dbab9a8b6ee85103e421bcf12650ccb8", element="0dfce294-f2d0-4644-bc80-a38597c32539")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="dbab9a8b6ee85103e421bcf12650ccb8", element="16820b29-5aaa-4c8c-b088-e10861f680bb")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="dbab9a8b6ee85103e421bcf12650ccb8", element="2ac9ce4c-e135-45c2-b098-fd1f0e7b91ea")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="dbab9a8b6ee85103e421bcf12650ccb8", element="990e20ea-f08a-4510-aaf9-1d08bdc6e9aa")>
```

How can I transform this output to have my targeted output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text value might be hidden.Try with `TagPhoto.get_attribute("textContent")`

```
for TagPhoto in TagsPhoto :
  print (TagPhoto.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print(TagPhoto.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Comment: then a blank appears

Comment: with get attribute : None
None
None
None
None
None

Comment: Do you get the same with `print(TagPhoto.get_attribute("innerText"))`?